# playing mp4 video without file header

Tags: video, gstreamer, mp4, h.264, quicktime

I am building some hardware and software for a video camera recorder. The hardware captures the data as it is being written to a SD card, and transfers the data to the PC that displays the video.

I need help to decode and display video that does not have the header of the mp4 file. Corresponding to capturing and displaying video after the video has started.

I can play my sample video with Gstreamer

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=full.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! autovideosink
```

If I take a middle portion of the file

```
tail -c $(( 10*1024*1024 )) full.mp4 | head -c $(( 5*1024*1024 )) > middle.mp4
```

-I am not sure how the play the file any longer.

**My question is:**
How do I play this file that is lacking the header of the mp4 file?

Extra info about the sample video (full.mp4)

```
gst-discoverer-1.0 file:///home/username/Videos/full.mp4 -v
Analyzing file:///home/quist/Videos/full.mp4
Done discovering file:///home/quist/Videos/full.mp4

Topology:
  container: video/quicktime
    audio: audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, level=(string)2, base-profile=(string)lc, profile=(string)lc, codec_data=(buffer)1210, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
      Tags:
        audio codec: MPEG-4 AAC audio
        maximum bitrate: 256000
        bitrate: 3108
        language code: en
        encoder: Lavf55.33.100
        container format: Quicktime
      
      Codec:
        audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, level=(string)2, base-profile=(string)lc, profile=(string)lc, codec_data=(buffer)1210, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
      Additional info:
        None
      Stream ID: ac6b090d044d63146735090a310b819cd64304c2ee05c9ee590009622318d12b/002
      Language: en
      Channels: 2 (front-left, front-right)
      Sample rate: 44100
      Depth: 32
      Bitrate: 3108
      Max bitrate: 256000
    video: video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.1, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640029ffe1001967640029acd9405005bb0110000003001000000780f183196001000468efbcb0, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)60/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
      Tags:
        video codec: H.264 / AVC
        language code: en
        bitrate: 8082504
        encoder: Lavf55.33.100
        container format: Quicktime
      
      Codec:
        video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.1, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640029ffe1001967640029acd9405005bb0110000003001000000780f183196001000468efbcb0, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)60/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
      Additional info:
        None
      Stream ID: ac6b090d044d63146735090a310b819cd64304c2ee05c9ee590009622318d12b/001
      Width: 1280
      Height: 720
      Depth: 24
      Frame rate: 60/1
      Pixel aspect ratio: 1/1
      Interlaced: false
      Bitrate: 8082504
      Max bitrate: 0

Properties:
  Duration: 0:00:18.167000000
  Seekable: yes
  Live: no
  Tags: 
      video codec: H.264 / AVC
      language code: en
      bitrate: 8082504
      encoder: Lavf55.33.100
      container format: Quicktime
      audio codec: MPEG-4 AAC audio
      maximum bitrate: 256000
```

Comment: You don't. MP4 is not a streaming file format. You can improve the situation with fragmented MP4 files - but I think you want another file format..

Comment: If there's no sound involved then just send the video picture (is encoded as H.264) without first putting into an MP4 container. H264 can stream frame by frame.

Comment: I am not interested in the audio. The video is stream-format=avc and as I understand it is not suitable for streaming. How do I pass the video to the decoder when I am tapping into a data stream? The video resolution, bitrate and framerate is always the same from the camera recorder, so I guess I need to preload the decoder with this information and them feed the H.264 frames. Can you help me put together a Gstreamer pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can't truncate an MP4 with head/tail - you could do it with a MPEG-2 Transport Stream probably not entirely without issues.

But instead of head/tail you could use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i full.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:10:00 -to 00:20:00 middle.mp4
```